# CKEditor add unkown pattern at end of each line, and line break

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in my project, and everything is working well, but something weird happens. The Editor adds unknown patterns like "nn" or "n" at end of each line and line break.
Here is html code

```
<div class="contanier">
  <textarea name="content" id="content" class="ckeditor"></textarea>  
</div>
```

Here is my js code

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('content',{
          height:300,
          filebrowserUploadUrl:"upload.php",
          filebrowserUploadMethod: "form",
          extraPlugins:"colorbutton",
          })
```

[Here is the content I write the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6EFh.png)

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData();
console.log(data);
```

[Here is the output form function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ6So.png)
[This is output in the browers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwRCz.png)